# Robotium - How to check view's visibility value

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, robotium, ui-testing

I want to check if view is visible, so I used isShown() method on view, but it's quite useless because I create my own views and these depends on id, so here's example view:

```
private static final String BTN_ADD_CURRENCY_ALERT = "action_add_currency_alert";

private View btn_AddAlert() {
    return mainHelper.getView(BTN_ADD_CURRENCY_ALERT);
}
```

Here is body of getView();

```
public View getView(String id) {
    return solo.getView(id);
}
```

Then I want to see if this element is visible (if not then should return false).

I call this like this

```
if (btn_addAlert().isShown()){...}
```

And the problem is that when I call `btn_addAlert()` and view is not visible I get AssertionFailedError and it's not even going to isShown().

I catched exception

```
private boolean catcher() {
    try {
        btn_addAlert().isShown();
        return true;
    } catch (AssertionFailedError e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

but it's wrong way because exceptions are not for this and also I have to wait whole timeout time to make it throw exception. Then it just return false.

So what can I do in this situation?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it like

```
 if(v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
       // do you stuff here
```

Comment: I think his problem is more complicated. It's not just how to find function "isShown".

Comment: btn_addAlert() - here's the problem. It will change nothing because getVisibility() won't be casted.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're already using this method:

```
public View getView(String id) {
    return solo.getView(id);
}
```

to check if this view is visible you can use:

```
 switch (getView("R.id.button").getVisibility()) {
        case (View.VISIBLE): {
            break;
        }
        case (View.INVISIBLE): {
            break;
        }

        case (View.GONE): {
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

In your exact case try to use `btn_addAlert().getVisibility()` instead of `getView("R.id.button").getVisibility()`.

Hope it will help

**EDIT:** Try to use one of these listeners to check if view's visibility has changed:

- using `ViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener`

  ```
     btn_addAlert().setTag(myView.getVisibility());
     btn_addAlert().getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
          int newVis = btn_addAlert().getVisibility();
          if((int)btn_addAlert().getTag() != newVis) {
              btn_addAlert().setTag(myView.getVisibility());
              //visibility has changed
             //here you can use my "switch" statement
          }
      }
   });
  ```

Check: [Handle a view visibility change without overriding the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777597/handle-a-view-visibility-change-without-overriding-the-view)

- using `OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener`:

  ```
  View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
  decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
      (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
          // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
          // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
          if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
              // TODO: The system bars are visible. Make any desired
              // adjustments to your UI, such as showing the action bar or
              // other navigational controls.
          } else {
             // TODO: The system bars are NOT visible. Make any desired
             // adjustments to your UI, such as hiding the action bar or
             // other navigational controls.
          }
      }
  });
  ```

Check: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html

Comment: This is just switch version of answer below. I want to do something until view is visible so use while loop but if view is not visible it won't return false and skip loop. It will throw exception and will mark my test as failed. It crashes when I getView and view is not visible, because it's searching for it, and it's gone so it throws an exception.

Comment: Nope. Guy below is using mistical `v`, I'm using direct `Robotium` code, so that's not equal. Don't use loops where purpose is for listeners