# Wait until android View visibility is visible for getX returns correct values to center in parent

Tags: android

I want to animate a view to the center of it's parent when it becomes visible.

I use `view.getX()` to calculate the center, but if I log

```
Log.e("YYY animate", parentCenterX + " " + mStarIcon.getWidth() + " " + mStarIcon.getX());
```

It returns a wrong `getX` value thus the view is not centered properly.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777597/handle-a-view-visibility-change-without-overriding-the-view), I found a solution to wait until `getX()` returns correct values:

```
mAnagramSummary
    .getViewTreeObserver()
    .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            private boolean mChanged = false;
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Log.e("YYY global", (mChanged ? "true" : "false") + mAnagramSummary.getVisibility());
                if (mAnagramSummary.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    if (!mChanged) {
                        mChanged = true;
                        mAnagramSummary.animateSummary();
                    }
                } else {
                    mChanged = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: why do you need better solution?

Comment: it looks weird!