# Observable/LiveData of ActionBar visibility?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am trying to see if it is possible to create an observable, that would notify when action bar visibility changes.

Something in a way of

```
LiveData<Boolean> actionBarVisibility;
```

So that other UI can be updated when actionBar is shown/hidden?
I found this [little trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32778292/813268) to identify the view visibility change events, but cannot figure out how to apply it to actionBar, since its view is not accessible to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can observe the state of Boolean!

**Inside ViewModel**

```
var isActionBarVisible: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
```

set visibility

```
isActionBarVisible.postValue(true)
```

set invisibility

```
isActionBarVisible.postValue(false)
```

====

**Inside View** (`Activity` or `Fragment`)

```
viewProvider!!.isActionBarVisible.observe(this, Observer {
        if (it!!) {
            // on visible of action bar
        } else {
           // on invisible of action bar
        }
    })
```

Comment: I am sorry, but that is not the question I asked - observing a boolean is simple, I agree, how do I hook into ActionBar of an activity, to update that value when visibility actually changes?