# Is there a better way to detect when Preference is not visible and then stop my Handler

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, android-handler

I have this basic `Preference` subclass that I have a `Handler` in. It will fire every second but it will not stop if the custom `Preference` is no more visible.

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:layout="@layout/pref_category_text"
    android:title="@string/pref_category_stat_out_title">

    <com.sunlux.smartpower.extended.preferences.ShowStatPreference android:key="@string/pref_key_show_stat" />
</PreferenceCategory>


public class ShowStatPreference extends Preference {

    private long MEGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L;
    private TextView bytesStat;
    private Handler mHandler;

    /**
     * Timer for updating stat
     */
    private final Runnable statRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setStatSomething();
            startStatTimer();
        }
    };

    public ShowStatPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ShowStatPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ShowStatPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.show_stat_preference);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        startStatTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
        holder.itemView.setClickable(false); // disable parent click
        bytesStat = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.bytes);
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
    }

    private void startStatTimer() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(statRunnable, 1000);
    }

    private void setStatSomething(){
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I could through listeners and send a message to make it stop when I change tab in the `PagerAdapter`, or if app is closing.

Is this my only chose here?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [onDetached()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference.html#onDetached()) to remove the handler when your setting page is closed. Something like this:

```
@Override public void onDetached() {
  super.onDetached();
  mHandler.removeCallbacks(statRunnable);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that would work but In my 'FragmentPagerAdapter' I have 5 'Fragment' and the 'getCount()' return 5 so the 'PreferenceFragmentCompat' is never removed. Think I will go with greenrobot:eventbus

Comment: Is that a dirty solution using greenrobot:eventbus?

Comment: Since I have the Handler on delay already set up, when that fire every second it could read som global variable that was set by the 'ViewPager', that will tell if its the current visible 'Fragment' right?

Comment: `Is that a dirty solution using greenrobot:eventbus?` yes, your preference will dependent to the EventBus.

Comment: `Since I have the Handler on delay already set up, when that fire every second it could read som global variable that was set by the 'ViewPager', that will tell if its the current visible 'Fragment' right?` that should work, but the preference still become dependent to the ViewPager.  How about listening to your View visibility changes inside the `onBindViewHolder`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777597/handle-a-view-visibility-change-without-overriding-the-view

Comment: Or just check the View visibility in the handler.

Comment: But the 'PreferenceFragmentCompat' is only loaded once, going back and forth between tabs and the 'PreferenceFragmentCompat' is alive, 'onBindViewHolder' is only called once. To test for the View visibility seam to be so much problem with I read

Comment: I created a 'getViewTreeObserver' for one of the 'TextViews' on the 'Pref' and when 'onGlobalLayout()' fire the 'getVisibility()' is always 'View.VISIBLE' even I go to other tabs in the 'ViewPager'. This must be becauase the Pref Frag is not unloaded