# How to know primary fragment item of FragmentStateAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2, fragmentstateadapter

I have a view pager type `FragmentStateAdapter` and would like to know when the primary fragment is in position e.g. 100% visible.  Does `FragmentStateAdapter` even support this? I've already tried approaches on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57885849/in-androidx-fragment-app-fragment-setuservisiblehint-is-deprecated-and-not-exec) with no luck.

Each fragment in the pager has some control over the host activity, but the control must be mutually exclusive. So like for example depending on which fragment is 100% visible, a button in the host activity layout will change color. But the color must depend on which fragment is primary, not on which fragment is resumed (adjacent fragment which are not visible can be in resumed state for example).

I am using `ViewPager2` and the widget class.

**edit**

Maybe an alternative is use like a [global layout change listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777597/handle-a-view-visibility-change-without-overriding-the-view) to test if the root layout of the fragment is 100% displayed?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should use a [ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback)

The `onPageSelected()` callback will be called when the page is selected, and you can base your logic on the position of the ViewPager.

```
viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(
        object: ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                super.onPageSelected(position)
                when (position) {
                    0 -> {
                        //Set button color
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        //Set button color to something else
                    }
                    else -> {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
)
```

If using the type of fragment currently showing would suit your needs better than using the position, you can use references to the fragments in the adapter, see here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36504458/4409409

Comment: That could work, another observation is the fragment is onResumed by the pager.